# Data encryption using Crypt::CBC

Tags: perl, encryption

We have used Perl's module Crypt::CBC for encrption the data.
The code looks like

```
use Crypt::CBC;
my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new( -key    => 'herearemykey',
                              -cipher => 'Blowfish'
                            );

my $ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt($password);
```

But we are getting different cipher text for the same plain text. Is there any other method for encrypting the plain text results in same cipher text?

Comment: Warning, Will Robinson: if you don't store the (random) IV with your encrypted data, you will loose access to your data. Pre-pending the IV is the most obvious choice taken (as you will need it when decrypting the first block).

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want the encrypted result to remain the same given the same plain text?  To do this provides information that needn't be given.  If you insist, you might look at providing a common `salt` as described [here](https://metacpan.org/module/Crypt%3a%3aCBC).

Answer (score 1):

This is considered a feature of ciphers in [CBC mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29). There's an initial random IV, and then each plaintext block is XOR'd with the previous ciphertext block. This prevents certain clever attacks that are possible with the straightforward ECB mode, where two identical plaintext blocks will come out the same.

It's rarely important that the ciphertext come out identically; it just needs to be decrypted correctly on the other end. As a rule, always use CBC mode unless you have a specific reason not to.  Even when you have a specific reason, there is probably a better alternative than the straightforward, naive ECB mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same ciphertext for given plaintext you have to pass also the same IV (initialization vector) to CBC - like this:

```
 my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new( -key => 'herearemykey',
                               -cipher => 'Blowfish', 
                               -iv => 'randomXY', 
                               -header => 'none' );
```